# ¿Por qué cuando cambio de True a False en el parámetro as_index en groupby, las columnas agrupadas no se muestran?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un dataframe que quiero agrupar por la columna *books*

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'books':['bk1','bk1','bk1','bk2','bk2','bk3'], 'price': [12,12,12,15,15,17]})
print(df)

     books  price
    0   bk1     12
    1   bk1     12
    2   bk1     12
    3   bk2     15
    4   bk2     15
    5   bk3     17

df.groupby(['books'], as_index=True).agg(asd = ('price', sum))

       asd
books     
bk1     36
bk2     30
bk3     17
```

Pero quisiera que el dataframe resultado tenga la siguiente forma:

```
    books  asd
0   bk1     36
1   bk2     30
2   bk3     17
```

Al cambiar `as_index = False`, el resultado se muestra así:

```py
df.groupby(['books'], as_index=False).agg(asd = ('price', sum))
   asd
0  bk1
1  bk2
2  bk3
```

Por favor, su gentil ayuda.

Comment: En StackOverflow **en español** utilizamos la lengua de Cervantes para preguntas, respuestas y comentarios. Por favor, publica en español. Un saludo.

Comment: O publica tu pregunta en StackOverflow en ingles.

Comment: Bien, pero debes editar la pregunta, por favor. De lo contrario será borrada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo único que deberías hacer es resetear el índice después del groupby:

```
df.groupby(['books']).agg(asd=('price', sum)).reset_index()
```

`as_index` por defecto es True, por lo que no es necesario pasarlo.